# Change JSON date to real date

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, variables, javascript-objects

I have only recently started to learn javascript, so I apologise for the beginner question.
What I am trying to do is change the SentDate I am accessing via an external JSON file to a more readable dd/mm/yyyy format. I have created a loop, and tried to make the changes here, but it's not behaving how it should.

This is my JSON file:

```
[
{
   "Name":"John Smith",
   "FromName":"Peter A",
   "FromEmail":"test@notreal.com",
   "ReplyTo":"test@notreal.com",
   "SentDate":"2020-11-11 19:21:00",


},
{
    "Name":"Jane Doe",
   "FromName":"Bob Richards",
   "FromEmail":"test2@notreal.com",
   "ReplyTo":"test2@notreal.com",
   "SentDate":"2019-11-11 19:21:00",
}
```

]

This is my Javascript:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET","data/informationdata.json", false);
  request.send(null);
  var abcPre = JSON.parse(request.responseText);  
  console.log("type of data: "+typeof(abcPre));
  
  for(var i = 0; i < abcPre.length;i++){
    if (abcPre.SentDate = [] ){
      abcPre.SentDate = new Date (SentDate).toLocaleDateString("en-GB").split("-");
      console.log(abcPre[i].SentDate);
     }

  }
```

Can someone please help point out where I am going wrong with trying to change the date?

Kind thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the revised code, which is now at least returning something. The result is 'Invalid Date' but its progress:

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET","data/informationdata.json", false);
  request.send(null);
  var abcPre = JSON.parse(request.responseText);  
  console.log("type of data: "+typeof(abcPre));
  
  for(var i = 0; i < abcPre.length;i++){
    if (abcPre.SentDate = [] ){
      abcPre[i].SentDate = new Date (abcPre.SentDate).toLocaleDateString("en-GB").split("-");
    console.log(`new date ${abcPre.sentDate}`);
     }

  }
```

Thank you again.

Comment: the result of `.toLocaleDateString("en-GB")` doesn't have any `"-"` in it: `11/11/2019`

Comment: Is your loop even working ? From what I understand, ``abcPre`` is the result of your request so your array of object. Which mean ``abcPre.SentDate`` doesn't exist on your if statement, while ``abcPre[i].SentDate`` do.

Comment: Hi. Good pick up. I have now updated my code in the first post. I think all I have to do now is get the new date format to actually be something which will work instead of 'invalid date'. I did test with Date.now() which returns a result. Obviously not correct, but at least its progress in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much to everyone who helped me with a solution.
I finally have it working.

Here it is:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < abcPre.length;i++){
  console.log(abcPre[i]);
  if (abcPre.SentDate = []) {
    abcPre[i].SentDate = new Date (abcPre[i].SentDate).toLocaleDateString("en-GB").split("-");
    console.log(`new date ${abcPre.sentDate}`);
     }

     else {
       console.log(`re-check date IF statement`);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < abcPre.length;i++){
    if (abcPre[i].SentDate == [] ){
      abcPre[i].SentDate = new Date (abcPre.SentDate).toLocaleDateString("en-GB").split("-");
    console.log(`new date ${abcPre.sentDate}`);
     }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for those who have commented so far. I have followed your advice, and am now getting an 'invalid date' return, which means its some kind of progress.
I have updated my first post with the revised code.

Comment: check out new response

Comment: Hi Radeanu. Just tested your response, and I am not getting a console log or date change. I think it might be because of the IF statement. I am still trying to figure out the solution. New day, fresh perspective (I hope). Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d1="2019-12-29 19:21:00"; 
  var d2=d1.split(" ");
  var d3=d2[0];
  var d4=d3.split("-").reverse().join("-");
  console.log(d4) // Output 29-12-2019
  var d5=d4+" "+d2[1]
  console.log(d5);  // Output 29-12-2019 19:21:00
```

```js
var d1="2019-12-29 19:21:00"; 
  var d2=d1.split(" ");
  var d3=d2[0];
  var d4=d3.split("-").reverse().join("-");
  console.log(d4) // 29-12-2019
  var d5=d4+" "+d2[1]
  console.log(d5);  // 29-12-2019 19:21:00
```

Comment: If your problem is solve then please mark the best answer